# What is the solution according to the following parameters? (equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-programming

The equation would accept x,y and output z where

As X approaches infinity and Y approaches infinity, Z approaches 0

As X approaches infinity and Y approaches 0, Z approaches 0

As X approaches 0 and Y approaches infinity, Z approaches infinity

As X approaches 0 and Y approaches 0, Z approaches 0

I have very little knowledge in equation construction.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 'function' instead of 'equation'?

Comment: Does something like $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ work?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of equations satisfying the conditions you present.

Note that an equation in the $xyz$-space is a rule 
$$f(x,y,z)=0$$
where $f$ is some conditions involving $x,y$ and $z$.

To construct *one* such rule $f$ we may look upon the conditions you pose and divide the $xy$-plane in disjoint pieces in which the conditions live.

We may for example consider 
$$S_1=\{(x,y):\,|x|>1, \, |y|>1 \}$$
$$S_2=\{(x,y):\,|x|>1, \, |y|\leq 1 \}$$
$$S_3=\{(x,y):\,|x|\leq1, \, |y|> 1 \}$$
$$S_4=\{(x,y):\,|x|\leq1, \, |y|\leq 1 \}$$

- On $S_1$ we can define $z=f(x,y)= 1/x$, then $z$ will go to 0 as $x$ and $y$ tends to infinity.
- On $S_2$ we can define $z=f(x,y)= y$, then $z$ will go to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity and $y$ tends to 0.
- On $S_3$ we can define $z=f(x,y)= y^8 +7$, then $z$ will go to infinity as $x$ tends to 0 and $y$ tends to infinity.
- On $S_4$ we can put $z=f(x,y)= xy$, which goes to 0 as $x$ and $y$ tends to 0.

In retrospective, we can of course take $f(x,y)=0$ everywhere except on $S_3$ where we can take $f(x,y)=y$. Also, this is just *one* (quiet ugly, but straight forward) way of constructing a solution.